# How to extend the RQRequestProcess release button

Tags: acumatica

My client has a requirement which forces me to move data between the RQRequest record to the RQRequisition record.  I chose to extend the Create Requisitions' processing screen 'Release' button.  I use Acumatica framework, to add the appropriate graph handlers during the Release method.  I noticed the 'Release' method actually resides in the nested class 'RQRequestProcessing'.  So is it possible to extend the release method?  Not sure if I can create a graph extension from a FilteredProcessing type.

Comment: In which form do you try to extend it? To which graph it relates? Which DAC you'll need to extend?

Comment: Screen ID RQ504000.  This screen allows me to create Requisitions.  I extend graph RQRequestProcess, which creates Requisitions from the related Requests.  That is the BLC for the screen.  However there are no PXAction handlers in that graph.  Only in the nested class 'RQRequestProcessing'.  I have a DAC extension for RQRequest, which contains some data I wish to feed the RQRequisition record, during the time of creation.  So that is why I choose the processing screen 'Create Requisitions'.